# c# datagridviewImageColumn can't display image from url

Tags: c#, datagridview, bitmap

```
    private Bitmap getBMP(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        myRequest.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = myResponse.GetResponseStream();
        Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(myResponse.GetResponseStream());
        myResponse.Close();
        return bmp;
    }
```

I created a dataGridView and added two dataGridViewImageColumn.
I got the Bitmap from the image url using above getBMP method
and added Bitmap to the dataGridView
I have tested for three cases
I don't know why Test1 succeeds and the other test(2,3) fails.

**Test 1. Bitmap loaded successfully**

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(getBMP(url1), getBMP(url2));
```

**Test 2. Failed to show bitmap**

```
Bitmap bmpOptImg = new Bitmap(getBMP(url1));
Bitmap bmpImg = new Bitmap(getBMP(url2));    
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(bmpOptImg , bmpImg);
```

**Test 3. Failed to show bitmap**

```
Bitmap bmpOptImg = (Bitmap)(getBMP(url1)).Clone();
Bitmap bmpImg = (Bitmap)(getBMP(url2)).Clone();
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(bmpOptImg , bmpImg);
```

There is no exception in Test2,3
But, Bitmap is not visible and dataGridView row color turns black

Comment: The 2nd method you are using 'new' which create an empty object.  The 3 method you are using Clone which again only creates the structure of the bitmap with no image.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks to you, I knew what the problem was.